# gitlab-ci.yml being ignored

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

my git  run only  one project in   .gitlab-ci.yml  file ,

gitlab-ci.yml:

include:

- 'services-foreign/foreign-mfo-service/ci.yml'
- 'services-foreign/foreign-tradernet-service/ci.yml'
- 'services/user-service/ci.yml'
- 'bpm-server/ci.yml'
- 'services/biometry-service/ci.yml'
- 'config-server/ci.yml'

if I comment all projects except for one of any, it will execute exactly it, if I delete all projects from the gitlab-ci.yml (remove the include option) file and run stages in it, pipline does not start at all.

Answer (score -1):

sorry  ,  in all  my ci   files I a have  job's  with ......  same names((  this is not right   in all ci jobs must have differents names
my fault